# Jmeter Plugin Didn't Display The Result

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm having problem with the error that jp@gc plugin in jmeter didn't show the result csv and image. Can you help me to solve the problem ?

Ther configuration of jp@gc graphs generator:

[meter-plugibn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51eA2.png)

The error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find specified JTL file: C:\Users\ryard\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\hasil\out\result.csv
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.checkParams(PluginsCMDWorker.java:90) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.doJob(PluginsCMDWorker.java:104) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmd-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:222) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137) ~[jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:492) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
2020-02-10 15:02:17,808 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is about `C:\Users\ryard\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\hasil\out\result.csv` file missing, this is so called [JTL Result File](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) from which the charts are generated.

Make sure to [run JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l C:\Users\ryard\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\hasil\out\result.csv
                                         ^^^^^^^^this is needed for generating result file
```

and Graphs Generator Listener should start working as expected.

Also be aware that starting from JMeter 3.0 there is [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) with interactive zoomable charts, you might want to consider using it for reporting instead.